# Why would GetType on a HTMLControl return NULL?

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms

I have an ASP page with a jQuery datepicker field as such:

```
<input type="text" id="txtDtSentToCIS" class="datepicker" name="txtDtSentToCIS" style="height: 14px; width: 70px" />
```

I'm using C# and trying to push a value to the field using this code in code-behind:

```
txtDtSentToCIS.Text = (DT["CSE_Snt_TO_dt"].ToString());
```

The right half of that expression DOES return a valid date from the dataset.  When I put my mouse over the control name (in break mode), it indicates the field class is null.  When I go to the Immediate window, it tells me this:

?txtDtSentToCIS.GetType()

'((object)(((ASP.webform1_aspx)this).txtDtSentToCIS))' is null

All I can think of is that the proper class isn't referenced, but I have "using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;" at the top of my code-behind.  All the fields on my form which are `"<asp:Textbox>"` work fine, it's the `"<input type="text">"` fields that are giving me this error.

Any ideas??

Comment: Add runat=server to ur html control

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only controls having attribute `runat="server"` are accesible from code behind.

So you need to have

```
<input type="text" id="txtDtSentToCIS" runat="server" class="datepicker"
  name="txtDtSentToCIS" style="height: 14px; width: 70px" />
```

or you could use a `TextBox` control

```
<asp:TextBox id="txtDtSentToCIS" runat="server" CssClass="datepicker" 
  style="height: 14px; width: 70px"/>
```